# Copy values from object array to input fields in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, forms, input

I have an array like this:

```
[
 {
  name: "simon",
  surname: "Bi"
 },
 {
  name: "Frank",
  surname: "Bour"
 }
]
```

I print all data in a table and I want to edit this values:

```
name1 - surname1 - edit1 - remove1
name2 - surname2 - edit2 - remove2
```

When I press "edit", I want to copy the user's data to input fields (so just 2 fields, name and surname), so I can change data and update the array but I don't know how to that in AngularJS.

JS:

```
angular.
   module('peopleList').
   component('peopleList', {
      templateUrl: "list.template.html",
      controller:
            function peopleListController(){
                var self = this;

                self.people = [
                    {
                        name: "Simon",
                        surname: "Bo",
                    }
                ];

                //add
                self.addPerson = function(itemToAdd) {
                    this.people.push(angular.copy(itemToAdd))
                }

                //remove
                self.delete = function(item) {
                    var index = this.people.indexOf(item);
                    this.people.splice(index, 1);
                }

                //edit
                self.edit = function(item){
                code
                }
            }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="$ctrl.addText(form)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="itemToAdd.name" placeholder="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
                <input id="surname" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="itemToAdd.surname" placeholder="surname" required>
               <button ng-click="$ctrl.addPerson(itemToAdd)" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>
            </div>
</form>


<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Surname</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Actions</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in $ctrl.people | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy: $ctrl.orderProp">
                    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.surname}}</td>
                    <td class="edit" ng-click="$ctrl.edit(person)" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">Edit</td>
                    <td class="remove" ng-click="$ctrl.delete(person)" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold; color: red;">X</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Provide some code please.

Comment: ok I added the code

Comment: @razer90 did you sort out ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it's almost self explanatory,just used `ng-model and ng-hide/ng-show` to achieve this.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$filter){


$scope.editField={};
  
  $scope.edit = function(index){
    $scope.editField[index] = !$scope.editField[index] ;
    };

$scope.data = [{name: "simon",
surname: "Bi"
},
{name: "Frank",
surname: "Bour"
}];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" class="widget-content" ng-controller="Ctrl">

                <table>
          <tr ng-repeat="emp in data">
                      <td>{{$index+1}} </td>
                      <td ng-hide="editField[$index]"> {{emp.surname}}</td>
                      <td ng-hide="editField[$index]">{{emp.name}} </td>
            <td ng-show="editField[$index]"><input type="text" ng-model="emp.surname"/></td>
            <td ng-show="editField[$index]"><input type="text" ng-model="emp.name"/></td>
            <td ng-click="edit($index)"><button>{{editField[$index]? 'Save': 'Edit'}}</button></td>
  </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
```

Comment: I updated my question with the code...can you take a look?

Comment: Yes I have seen but the example I've provided works the same way you just need to hold the values of ng-models to get the latest updated values.And may be if you can add save function to copy those to a new array like `$scope.newData = angular.copy($scope.data);`

Comment: maybe it's easier than I think, but I can't apply your example to my code...I tried to change ng-model to my input fields but with any result..can u edit my code?

Comment: `<td ng-hide="editField[$index]"> {{emp.surname}}</td>
                      <td ng-hide="editField[$index]">{{emp.name}} </td>
            <td ng-show="editField[$index]"><input type="text" ng-model="emp.surname"/></td>
            <td ng-show="editField[$index]"><input type="text" ng-model="emp.name"/></td>` try implementing this part

Comment: ok I understood your code, but I don't want use this trick (show/hide..). I just want copy some values to input field (the SAME input field that I use to add people)..there is a way to do that?

Comment: Even for what you are asking you need `ng-show/ng-hide` (it's not a trick though) ok try using them but for your sake for the input fields assign a new ng-model object and add this in the edit function `$scope.newData = angular.copy($scope.data);` Now the `ng-model will be $scope.newData.name and $scope.newData.surname`